# Issue creating a VM in Ubuntu 20.04 with Vermin and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, kubernetes

I recently have bought a suscription to a ubuntu VPS server in order to play with kubernetes and I am trying to create a master and a node virtual machine following a tutorial that uses Vermin and Virtual Box for this purpose. I have installed Vermin and Virtualbox but when I try to create the virtual machine I get this error from virtual box.

`root@vmi1550660:~# vermin create ubuntu/focal64 --cpus 2 --mem 2048 master.sh ✔ Creating vm_01 from image ubuntu/focal64   exit status 1 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100% Interpreting /root/.vermin/images/vagrant/ubuntu/focal64.ova... OK. 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%... Progress state: VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed VBoxManage: error: Storage for the medium '/root/.vermin/vms/vm_01/ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.vmdk' is not created VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 1379 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp`

If I navigate to the Vermin folder and open the log file, I can see this error:

`root@vmi1550660:~/.vermin# cat log_2023-12.log  cannot ungzip image /root/.vermin/images/vagrant/ubuntu/focal64.ova, try untaring only... cannot ungzip image /root/.vermin/images/vagrant/ubuntu/trusty64.ova, try untaring only... cannot ungzip image /root/.vermin/images/vagrant/ubuntu/focal64.ova, try untaring only...`

Anyone has any solution to this?

I tried to reinstall VirtualBox to a previous version (6.0) but still not working

Comment: Please edit your question and use proper code formatting, it's very difficult to read.